# Stream plot of an autonomous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that I have the following ODE system of autonomous equations, where $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$ are all scrictly positives.

$$\dot{x} = a_1 x - a_2 xv$$
$$\dot{v} = a_3 xv - a_4v$$

How do I draw the phase portrait of this ODE? I know that the equilibrium points of this system are: $(0, 0), (\frac{a_1}{a_2}, \frac{a_3}{a_4})$. But since the unknown variables are all strictly positive, The only equilibrium points are $ (\frac{a_1}{a_2}, \frac{a_3}{a_4})$. I feel like calculating the jacobian matrix of the system and extracting the roots of the charactericti polynomial is not the right approach. What's the proper way of approacing this problem?

Comment: This simple predator-prey or Volterra-Lotka system has a first integral. The phase portrait is the contour plot of this first integral.